# How to scroll to top in antd steps. react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Steps component of `antd`. 
I want whenever a user goes to the next step or to the previous step the page should scroll to top. 
I use window.scrollTo(0, 0) and window.top=0; but it does not work. 
can anyone help how can I scroll to top.

```
previousStep = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    window.scrollTop = 0;
    const { currentStep } = this.state;
    this.setState({ currentStep: currentStep - 1 });
};
```

Comment: Are you using the browser body scrolling or do you have a custom scroll component (or element with `overflow-y: scroll`)?

Comment: Post your complete code. How much amount of data present on visible area?

Comment: thanks  for your time guys . i just got it fixed. in parent component there was a property overflow-x:hidden which was creating issue. Now even window.scrollTo(0,0) worked. thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
onstructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()   // Create a ref object 
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.myRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef}></div> 
}   // attach the ref property to a dom element
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: you can refer this for more detail https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: This will not solve the problem. `componentDidMount` executes only once.

Comment: No you can get myRef in previousStep  function also

Comment: thanks @ajeeshs for your time. i just got it fixed. in parent component there was a property overflow-x:hidden which was creating issue. Now even window.scrollTo(0,0) worked. thanks again. :-)

Comment: @AhmedWaqas thanks a ton, actually more than it. After wasting hours, I found this comment. My problem was not exactly same, but an overflow-hidden class was getting added.